# Nutch 1.9 command crawl is only fetching one level

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am a rookie in nutch. After few weeks playing with it. I can finally start crawling.

I installed nutch 1.9 and solr 4.1 and my seed.txt file only containing 1 url, and my regex-urlfiler.txt is set to accept everything. I am running this command:

```
bin/crawl urls crawl http://104.131.94.**:8983/solr/ 1 -depth 3 -topN 5
```

Here is the output:

```
Injector: starting at 2014-12-07 18:41:31
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: overwrite: false
Injector: update: false
Injector: Total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
Injector: Total number of urls after normalization: 1
Injector: Total new urls injected: 1
Injector: finished at 2014-12-07 18:41:33, elapsed: 00:00:01
Sun Dec 7 18:41:33 EST 2014 : Iteration 1 of 1
Generating a new segment
Generator: starting at 2014-12-07 18:41:34
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: false
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 50000
Generator: Partitioning selected urls for politeness.
Generator: segment: crawl/segments/20141207184137
Generator: finished at 2014-12-07 18:41:38, elapsed: 00:00:03
Operating on segment : 20141207184137
Fetching : 20141207184137
Fetcher: starting at 2014-12-07 18:41:39
Fetcher: segment: crawl/segments/20141207184137
Fetcher Timelimit set for : 1418006499487
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 50
Fetcher: time-out divisor: 2
QueueFeeder finished: total 1 records + hit by time limit :0
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
fetching http://www.wenxuecity.com/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=6
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=5
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=3
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=5
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=4
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
Fetcher: throughput threshold retries: 5
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
fetcher.maxNum.threads can't be < than 50 : using 50 instead
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0
-activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=0
-activeThreads=0
Fetcher: finished at 2014-12-07 18:41:42, elapsed: 00:00:02
Parsing : 20141207184137
ParseSegment: starting at 2014-12-07 18:41:43
ParseSegment: segment: crawl/segments/20141207184137
Parsed (17ms):http://www.wenxuecity.com/
ParseSegment: finished at 2014-12-07 18:41:46, elapsed: 00:00:02
CrawlDB update
CrawlDb update: starting at 2014-12-07 18:41:48
CrawlDb update: db: crawl/crawldb
CrawlDb update: segments: [crawl/segments/20141207184137]
CrawlDb update: additions allowed: true
CrawlDb update: URL normalizing: false
CrawlDb update: URL filtering: false
CrawlDb update: 404 purging: false
CrawlDb update: Merging segment data into db.
CrawlDb update: finished at 2014-12-07 18:41:49, elapsed: 00:00:01
Link inversion
LinkDb: starting at 2014-12-07 18:41:51
LinkDb: linkdb: crawl/linkdb
LinkDb: URL normalize: true
LinkDb: URL filter: true
LinkDb: internal links will be ignored.
LinkDb: adding segment: crawl/segments/20141207184137
LinkDb: finished at 2014-12-07 18:41:52, elapsed: 00:00:01
Dedup on crawldb
Indexing 20141207184137 on SOLR index -> http://104.131.94.36:8983/solr/
Indexer: starting at 2014-12-07 18:41:58
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
        solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
        solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
        solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
        solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth.username : use authentication (default false)
        solr.auth : username for authentication
        solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Indexer: finished at 2014-12-07 18:42:01, elapsed: 00:00:03
Cleanup on SOLR index -> http://104.131.94.36:8983/solr/
```

There are couple issues here:

1. the crawl didn't take my topN 5 instead it use topN =50000, then I took a look at the crawl script it is hard coded to 50000 doesn't really take -topN parameters. I guess I can just modify the script.
2. the depth 3 is also get ignored, and seems to me there is also no parameter in the script to take care the depth.

I can see a lot of examples are running command nutch crawl, but with 1.9 the command cannot be used anymore. I am really stuck here, any suggestion would be appreciated.

The solr indexing is working fine, I always got 1 documents indexed. And I tried several crawl-able websites, the script always stopped at the first level.

Thanks
Pengcheng

Answer (score 3):

It is working now, the first round only 1 page is fetched and second round is fetched lots of pages, I guess the number of rounds is same as depth.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use individual commands for web crawling. Then check how many pages could crawl in second run. If its 0 pages then check your include path in (should be like **+^http://www.google.com/**) regex-urlfilter.txt.

Refer how to run [Individual command](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3.4_Using_Individual_Commands_for_Whole-Web_Crawling)